# Python Variable Assignment by Index of Differing List Length

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, data-structures

I have large data sets that I am analyzing line by line. An example data line would be `100 0 0 100 1 0 100 2 0 100 3 0 100 4 0`. Here, the two entries that follow `100` contain information (deciphered to English) about the data. Hence, the first entry after `100` is always deciphered based on its value (either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4) and the second entry after `100` is always deciphered based on the value of entry 1 (i.e. if entry 1 = 0 entry 2 = ____, or if entry 1 = 1 entry 2 = _____ etc etc).

I have stored the data line in `data` as a list. There are always two entries following `100` but I cannot be sure how many occurrences of `100` there will be in a given line - the example data line has 5 instances of `100` but other lines have any number of instances.

Current Code: (disregard `column`, it is the original list I used to establish `data`)

```
data = [num for num in column[2:] if num != 100]
entry1 = data[1]
entry2 = data[2]
info_dict1 = {0: 'absolute', 1: 'minimum', 2: 'maximum', 3: 'median', 4: 'mode'}
info1 = info_dict1.get(entry1, 'not found')
info_dict2 = {'absolute': 'value', 'minimum': 'increase', 'maximum': 'increase'}
info2 = info_dict2.get(info1, 'not found')
print(info1, info2)
```

I am having trouble getting this to work for data lines with unknown occurrences of `100`. I am also struggling with finding an accurate Pythonic solution.

For the example data provided I expect the result to look like:
`absolute value minimum increase maximum increase median not found mode not found`

It is important to **note** that the the entries following 100 are not always ordered like the example line provided (i.e. the first entry could be any number 0-4 and the second entry will change depending on the first entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution for the answer you are expecting.

```
column = [100, 0, 0, 100, 1, 0, 100, 2, 0, 100, 3, 0, 100, 4, 0]
data = [num for num in column if num != 100] 
info_dict1 = {0: 'absolute', 1: 'minimum', 2: 'maximum', 3: 'median', 
4: 'mode'}
info_dict2 = {'absolute': 'value', 'minimum': 'increase', 'maximum': 
'increase'}
info1 = []

#Iterating the list in step of 2
for item in data[::2]:
    result = info_dict1.get(item, 'not found')
    info1.append(result)
    info1.append(info_dict2.get(result, 'not found'))

print(info1)
```